# Docker container fails to initalize from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and in the process of learning Docker Compose, using CentOS 8 as the host system.  All of these files are in the same directory and marked executable with mode 0755.

My main application is in `webapp.py`:

```python
import time

import redis
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
cache = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379)

def get_hit_count():
    retries = 5
    while True:
        try:
            return cache.incr('hits')
        except redis.exceptions.ConnectionError as exc:
            if retries == 0:
                raise exc
            retries -= 1
            time.sleep(0.5)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    count = get_hit_count()
    return 'Hello World! I have been seen {} times.\n'.format(count)
```

There is a matching `requirements.txt` file:

```
flask
redis
```

A `Dockerfile`:

```sh
FROM python:3.4-alpine
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "webapp.py"]
```

And a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

However, when I run `docker-compose up`, it fails by exiting the web app.  Compose outputs:

```
[root@localhost webappl]# docker-compose up
Starting webappl_redis_1 ... done
Starting webappl_web_1   ... done
Attaching to webappl_web_1, webappl_redis_1
redis_1  | 1:C 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.861 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis_1  | 1:C 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.861 # Redis version=6.2.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis_1  | 1:C 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.861 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis_1  | 1:M 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.863 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
redis_1  | 1:M 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.864 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_1  | 1:M 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.864 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
redis_1  | 1:M 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.864 # Server initialized
redis_1  | 1:M 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.864 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis_1  | 1:M 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.865 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.2.6
redis_1  | 1:M 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.865 * RDB age 4147 seconds
redis_1  | 1:M 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.865 * RDB memory usage when created 0.77 Mb
redis_1  | 1:M 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.865 # Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 0, keys expired: 0.
redis_1  | 1:M 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.865 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
redis_1  | 1:M 27 Dec 2021 09:03:35.865 * Ready to accept connections
webappl_web_1 exited with code 0
```

Why does it exit?

Comment: Jus wanted to add, whenever, I follow the steps from https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/, it works perfectly.

Comment: where are you exposing 5000 port that you are using in your docker-compose? Isnt your Webapp.py supposed to open that port?

Comment: Both Docker and Python normally run off of plain-text files, not images; I can't build a Docker image out of the PNG files you've attached here.  Can you edit the question and replace all of the images with the actual text of your application's source and output?

Comment: Please stop posting images if you need help

Comment: @silentsudo, Looks like gotta learn to use StackOverflow as much as the docker itself, lolz. Removed the images though.

Comment: If you directly run `./webapp.py` from the host (maybe in a virtual environment) does it stay running, or does it exit immediately?  I don't see a Flask `app.run()` call in what you include here.

Answer (score 0):

can you trying adding following to your web: after ports:? if stdin_open doesn't work, try stdin

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

Comment: still the webappl_web_1 container exits.

Comment: you need to stop existing docker-compose's containers using "docker-compose down"